# p:variable :: What does shaddowing mean and can I reassign a new value to a previously declared p:variable

Tags: xml, xproc

I've not tried it yet.

Can we update the value of p:variable anywhere else in the pipeline i.e. after its valid declaration at start of some step? If not then why? Also what is the best way of doing this, if I really need to do or at least simulate it.

Comment: Can you comment on why you need this? There might be other ways of achieving what you are trying to do.

Comment: Let's say I have a p:variable name='state', now below its declaration I'm going through a long p:choose and I want this state variable hold some value based on any p:when getting executed so that I could do something based on the variable [state]'s current value afterwards. What is the best way of achieving this in XProc if above is not possible?

Comment: You need to bend your mind to not need variables that way. You can however make use of arguments (options, params) for instance. Put the logic that depends on $state in a separate p:declare-step, then call that step from within the choose alternatives with the appropriate value of $state.

Comment: I could give a more detailed solution if you append a practical example case to the question..

Answer (score 0):

I forwarded your question to the xproc-dev mailinglist. Apparently, the recommendation seems to contradict itself. Section 5.7 ( http://www.w3.org/TR/xproc/#variables-options-parameters ) says quite explicitly that shadowing should be allowed in specific conditions. But section 3.2 ( http://www.w3.org/TR/xproc/#scoping ) says that reusing the same variable name in a scope is an error. The consensus was though that this should in principle work:

```
<p:variable name="myvar" select="1"/>
<p:group>
    <p:variable name="myvar" select="2"/>
```

However, XMLCalabash (0.9.40) chokes on this. You might try Calumet or other processors though..